# Set up X-axis and Y-axis on Jmeter graphic

Tags: graphics, jmeter

Basically I want to generate a graphic with a counter variable on X-axis and response time on Y-axis. I did a research and most of plugins can generate graphics but with X and Y axis predefined.

I would like to try any approach to avoid writing a report file myself, but if it is the only possible way, then please give an example on how to do it.