# Jmeter define X-axis value in graphs for two different use cases

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am almost new to Jmeter. We have some tests scripts to handle HTTP request and verify the answer from our SUT which is basically a web application.
Our challenge is that we want to customize the graphs generated by Jmeter.
This is the test script:
a) Send a load of HTTP requests from an API to the application (but the API won't send directly to the database !, there is a process to handle the data)
b) Run SSH commands to monitor the processes
c) keep the load for 10 minutes and check the graphs

So , We want to be able to do two things:
1) Execute some SSH commands towards the server to monitor the HW usage **(which is done already)**  and then display the output of this commands in a graph as function of a throughput defined in the test scenario 
2) Display the usual graphs (response time) as function of test data value, means we want to configure the X-axis parameter for the graphs

I found some links but not really enough I think:
[Set up X-axis and Y-axis on Jmeter graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418279/set-up-x-axis-and-y-axis-on-jmeter-graphic)
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SettingsPanel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you aware of [SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener)? It should be able to plot the responses from your SSH commands to the test timeline
2. There is a possibility to create a chart of a [custom variable(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which is being exposed via [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property
3. Finally it is possible to overwrite a "not-interesting" metric, i.e. [Latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) with a custom JMeter Variable using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the code like:

   ```
   prev.setLatency(123)
   ```

   or

   ```
   prev.setLatency(vars.get('your_variable') as long)
   ```

   Once done you should be able to use Latency vs Request per second chart of the HTML Reporting Dashboard in order to visualize your information.

   [image]

   You can amend the chart title by manipulating [`jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latencyVsRequest.title` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Comment: Thank you really !, that is exactly what we are looking for.

Comment: Hello again, I tried using the post processor to exchange the values but it didn't assign the value correctly.

Comment: Hello again, I tried using the post processor to exchange the values but it didn't assign the value correctly. This what I did: 1) prev.setSampleCount(vars.get(${ts-hit}) as long) and I put ${ts-hit}) in PEM Key field for the SSH command that should retrieve the RAM usage for example. But even I added my cutomized graph in user.properties the graph comes empty. This is the code from properties file:

Comment: jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_SSHMon-Samples-Collector-RAM.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_SSHMon-Samples-Collector-RAM.title=Chunk Hit
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_SSHMon-Samples-Collector-RAM.property.set_Y_Axis=Latency